# Problem with JpaRepository - getting static, non static error while using CRUDrepsosity of JpaRepository

Tags: jparepository

[Line 29 and Line 35 showing errors as seen in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jaNa.png)

I have tried making every function static still this is not solving the issue

To use the predefined function to save the data, I am trying to save the the data using CRUDrespsitory predefined function but I am not able to. What should I do?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.